# Send a group with a number selection field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send a group input, but there is also a number selection field. Everything is sent well.
 But the corresponding number is not sent and only 1 is sent.
I receive information in a loop
And inside the loop, I use the number iteration loop.
And I send via Ajax.
I just don't know how to get the name of the number
This is my problem with receiving

My codes:

```
 <?php foreach ($selecttiming as $row){?>
           <div>
             <select style="width: 80px;" class="" name="countnum">
               <?php
               for ($num=1; $num<100; $num++)
               {
                 echo '<option value="'.$num.'">' .$num. '</option>';
               }
               ?>
             </select>
             <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" id="<?= $row['id'] ?>" value="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
             <label style="font-size: 1.3em;" for="<?= $row['id'] ?>"><?= $row['title'] ?> <i style="color: #007fff;" class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></label>
           </div>
         <?php } ?>
```

```js
       $(document).on('click', '#submitcon2', function(e){
           var iddate=$('.content-current2').find('.deldatersel.activedeldatersel').attr('value');
         
           var data = $("#subtiming").serialize();
           $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type : 'POST',
             url  : '<?= URL ?>newproduct/addertiming2/'+iddate+'',
             data:data,
```

```
         function addertiming2($iddate,$data){
       $datesel=$data['check'];

     $counter=$data['countnum'];

     foreach ($datesel as $row) {
       $daters=$row;
         $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_time_jobs`
         (`time`,`tedad`,`active`,`dateid`)
         VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
         $result=self::$db->prepare($sql);
         $result->bindParam(1, $daters);
         $result->bindParam(2, $counter);
         $result->bindParam(3, $active);
         $result->bindParam(4, $deidbaskets);
         $query=$result->execute();
         }

       }
```

//I also want to send this value $counter with $datesel

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a#submit-link', function(e){
  e.preventDefault;
  var data = $('#form').serialize();
  console.log(data);
  //ajax call
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <select style="width: 80px;" class="" name="countnum[1]">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1">
</form>
<a href="#" id="submit-link" title="Link">Submit form</a>
```

I used test data:

```
rows total= 4;
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
  'countnum' => 
    array (size=4)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '3' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
  'check' => 
    array (size=4)
      1 => string 'checkbox1' (length=9)
      2 => string 'checkbox2' (length=9)
      3 => string 'checkbox3' (length=9)
      4 => string 'checkbox4' (length=9)
  'submit' => string 'Submit form' (length=11)
```

Now you can use `$key` in backend to get exact chosen values.

Comment: Thanks
But my problem is with php. There is no problem with Ajax
I receive the checkbox information and it runs inside the code loop
 And a new line is added to the database with each selection
But next to it is a number field where it is sent only 1
This is how the checkbox, for example, selects 1 and selects the number 2
Or select another checkbox to select the number 5.
My only problem is how to match that field to the checkbox.
I put the code I executed

Comment: I updated my code, You can use `row['id']` to separate selections by their row id.